# Come posso dire a una persona "take your time" in italiano?

Tags: translation

Come posso dire a una persona "take your time" oppure "make yourself at home" in italiano?

Grazie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per ***take your time*** potresti dire:

> - fai con calma
> - prenditi il tuo tempo
> - prenditi il tempo che ti serve
> - fai con comodo

Per ***make youself at home*** potresti dire:

> - mettiti comodo
> - mettiti a tuo agio
> - fai come se fossi a casa tua